# Convert dictionary format txt file into excel in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

For a txt file `result.txt` as follows:

```
[
  {
    "image_id": "42041",
    "mean_score_prediction": 4.996936075389385
  },
  {
    "image_id": "42039",
    "mean_score_prediction": 4.647608995437622
  },
  {
    "image_id": "42044",
    "mean_score_prediction": 3.9866196922957897
  },
  {
    "image_id": "42042",
    "mean_score_prediction": 3.9691513180732727
  },
  {
    "image_id": "42040",
    "mean_score_prediction": 4.303698152303696
  }
]
```

I want to convert it to a dataframe `df` then save as excel `result.xlsx`:

```
print(df)
   image_id  mean_score_prediction
0     42041               4.996936
1     42039               4.647609
2     42044               3.986620
3     42042               3.969151
4     42040               4.303698
```

How can I do this in Python? Thanks.

First I read the file in Python:

```
filename = 'result.txt'
with open(filename) as f:
    data = f.readlines()

print(data)
```

Output:

```
['[\n', '  {\n', '    "image_id": "42041",\n', '    "mean_score_prediction": 4.996936075389385\n', '  },\n', '  {\n', '    "image_id": "42039",\n', '    "mean_score_prediction": 4.647608995437622\n', '  },\n', '  {\n', '    "image_id": "42044",\n', '    "mean_score_prediction": 3.9866196922957897\n', '  },\n', '  {\n', '    "image_id": "42042",\n', '    "mean_score_prediction": 3.9691513180732727\n', '  },\n', '  {\n', '    "image_id": "42040",\n', '    "mean_score_prediction": 4.303698152303696\n', '  }\n', ']\n']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text file has json format, so you can use [`read_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) also if no extension `.json`:

```
df = pd.read_json('result.txt')
print (df)
   image_id  mean_score_prediction
0     42041               4.996936
1     42039               4.647609
2     42044               3.986620
3     42042               3.969151
4     42040               4.303698
```

Last write to excel by [`DataFrame.to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

```
df.to_excel('result.xlsx', index=False)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: with open("result.txt", 'r') as f:
   ...:     data = f.read()
   ...:

In [3]: data
Out[3]: '[\n  {\n    "image_id": "42041",\n    "mean_score_prediction": 4.996936075389385\n  },\n  {\n    "image_id": "42039",\n    "mean_score_prediction": 4.647608995437622\n  },\n  {\n    "image_id": "42044",\n    "mean_score_prediction": 3.9866196922957897\n  },\n  {\n    "image_id": "42042",\n    "mean_score_prediction": 3.9691513180732727\n  },\n  {\n    "image_id": "42040",\n    "mean_score_prediction": 4.303698152303696\n  }\n]'

In [6]: df = pd.read_json(data)

In [7]: df
Out[7]:
   image_id  mean_score_prediction
0     42041               4.996936
1     42039               4.647609
2     42044               3.986620
3     42042               3.969151
4     42040               4.303698
```